# How change size or image of Toggle Button in Report Builder 2.0?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I want to resize or change the toggle Image (red box) in Report Builder 2.0. Is there any possibility?
Or can i toggle my elements via the column (blue box)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's impossible to change the icon in the Report Builder 2.0 (or 3.0).

If you really wish to change the image you shouldn't use an ssrs report. Could create a custom view in windows forms, wpf or html (css) that has the same functionalities as the report viewer, which will take a lot of effort.

You could move the toggle function to another textbox inside your report but I'm afraid the same icon will be placed in front of it.

Comment: I tried to move it to another textbox and the icon was placed in front of it. I also think that it is not possible.

Comment: It isn't. So you'll have to deal with it or use something other than the Report Builder.